# TypeScript and Google Earth

Tags: typescript

The following code works. I can load a page and get the Earth to display.

I want to show the Navigation Control. If I uncomment the line in initCB it works.

I believe the code has a scope issue and need a nudge to get it working.

Thank you.

```
declare var google;

class GoogleEarth {

    static pluginInstance;

    static display() {

        google.load("earth", "1");
        google.setOnLoadCallback(init);
    }

    static ShowNavigation() {

        this.pluginInstance.getNavigationControl().setVisibility(this.pluginInstance.VISIBILITY_AUTO);
    }

    private static init() {

        google.earth.createInstance('map3d', initCB, failureCB);
    }

    private static initCB(instance) {

        this.pluginInstance = instance;
        this.pluginInstance.getWindow().setVisibility(true);
        //this.pluginInstance.getNavigationControl().setVisibility(this.pluginInstance.VISIBILITY_AUTO);
    }

    private static failureCB(errorCode) {}
}

GoogleEarth.display();
GoogleEarth.ShowNavigation();
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated based on your comment...

There are a combination of three issues here.

1. Race condition, where variables were used before they had been set, because they were being set in a callback, but used before the callback happened.
2. Scope issues. The callback functions were executing in the wrong scope.

These can be fixed using the following sample:

```
declare var google;

class GoogleEarth {

    private pluginInstance;

    constructor (private showNavigation = false){
    }

    display() {
        var self = this;
        google.load("earth", "1");
        google.setOnLoadCallback(function (instance) {
            google.earth.createInstance('map3d', function () {
                this.pluginInstance = instance;
                this.pluginInstance.getWindow().setVisibility(true);
                if (this.showNavigation) {
                    this.pluginInstance.getNavigationControl().setVisibility(this.pluginInstance.VISIBILITY_AUTO);
                }
            }, self.failureCB); 
        });
    }

    ShowNavigation() {

    }

    failureCB(errorCode) {}
}

var earth = new GoogleEarth(true);
earth.display();
```

I did mention there were three issues though!

The final problem is that the `instance` you are being passed doesn't have a function called `getWindow()` - so there is an error at this stage in the code. This is a case of double-checking the Google documentation.

Comment: I see where you're going showNavigation has the same issue as pluginInstance. It is still false by the time it gets to initCB even  when I pass true to display()

Here is the html to get this to work

<html>
<head>
  <title>Sample</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"> </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"> </script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="map3d" style="height: 400px; width: 600px;"></div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Thanks for the help Sohnee. This example gets an error on getWindow when I did the copy and paste. When I have time I will look and see if I caused a problem. I am new to JavaScript, so it seems that TypeScript, OOP and state full objects can be used but with the browser and interaction with libraries like Google Earth, we are still waiting for "events" to happen so that objects are fully realized? Then we can perform actions on them.

Comment: Yeah - this is a classes JavaScript scenario - callbacks running before something is ready on the one hand, and the meaning of `this` in different contexts on the other.